# How can I tell if a translation message exist for a given message key in a given locale?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

In a e-commerce application, I am translating all the entities for creating a receipt.

Sometimes, a product may have not been translated yet, in this case, I want to provide another message from the record in my database.

In a java spring boot 1.5.9 application, how can I tell if a translation message exists for a given message key in a given locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MessageSourceAccessor#getMessage`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/MessageSourceAccessor.html#getMessage-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) to read the message for your desired locale.

The signature is

```java
public String getMessage(String code, Locale locale)
                  throws NoSuchMessageException
```

If the message is not found with the provided locale, [`NoSuchMessageException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/NoSuchMessageException.html) will be thrown.